# How to get ALL the HTML tags associated with a specific id (Beautiful soup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML page that contains multiple links with the same reference as following:

```
<a href="1"><img src="myImage.png"></a>
<a href="1"><img src="myImage22.png"></a>
<a href="1"><img src="myImage33.png"></a>
```

When I am requesting the page to return all the tags (links) that have the `href` 1, it is returning only the first one. How to tell the code to return all the links not only the first one?

This is my code:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.myWebsite.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
author_name = soup.find('a', href= '1')
```

Comment: ``find()`` returns [only one result](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.myWebsite.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a', {'href':'1'}):
    print(link.getText())
```

or if you want to make a list out of them you can just do this:

```
author_names = [link.getText() for link in soup.find_all('a', {'href':'1'})]
```

The problem with your solution was that `find()` only returns the first result, while `find_all()` returns all of them. 
You can read up more on Beautiful Soup [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)